# Can't find anything using "screen" in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

Whenever I try to find the element i.e. `expect(screen.getByRole("heading", { level: 2 })).toBeInTheDocument();`  I get the message :

`TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "heading"`

However if I do

```
const { getByRole } = render(<NewCommentForm />);
expect(getByRole("heading", { level: 2 })).toBeInTheDocument();
```

It works.

Here is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "jest-axe": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.28.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5"
  }
}
```

And `setupTests.js`

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

Can you tell me why `screen` is not working properly when call `getByRole` method on it? It seems like `screen.getByText` works fine.

Comment: Please share your component code to have a better look of why it is failing.

Comment: did u forget render first, everything should render to screen. and you can even print out the container and see whats inside.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue, I didn't have the `render`. I should probably put it in `beforeEach` block.

Comment: I have the same problem and have render and beforeEach doesn't resolve it.